# I was trying to concatenate 3 columns in SQL from dbvisualizer

Tags: mysql, dbvisualizer

I was trying to concatenate 3 columns in SQL, but I getting error message as

> 1) [Error Code: -440, SQL State: 42884]  DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE:
>   -440, SQLSTATE: 42884, SQLERRMC: CONCAT;FUNCTION. 2) [Error Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -727, SQLSTATE: 56098, SQLERRMC: 2;-440;42884;CONCAT|FUNCTION

This is my query

```
select concat(number,ID,name) as MemberDetails from Member where number = '123'
```

Comment: Dont use the same alias as the table name.

Comment: I tried different name but still the same message

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with the schema. Specifically, it involves functions and procedures.

You have two SQL return codes, both of which are errors. The two codes are

`-440`: Routine &1 in &2 not found with specified parameters. A function or procedure with the specified name and compatible arguments was not found

and

`-727`: There actually isn't an error code named this. Did you mean `-747`?

In SQL, a negative number represents an unsuccessful call with an error.

You need a separate `alias` name. Also you might want to add the alias before the column name just in case there's disambiguation. Here's what it should look like.

```
select concat(number,ID,name) as M from Member where M.number = '123'
```

If neither of them worked, it is a problem with the SCHEMA, not with the above query.

Comment: Can you post your schema? I think the problem lies there

Comment: the schema name is 'onev'